# Would rather + Instead of

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language, would-rather

I know the idiom is "I would rather... Than" as in ”I'd rather play football than stay at home", but can I substitute "than" with "instead of"?

"I'd rather play football instead of stay at home". Is this sentence correct?

Comment: You can look [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164010/when-to-use-rather-than-versus-instead-of)

Comment: _Would rather_ is normally followed by _than_. You can use _instead of_ with other expressions, for example "I wish I was out playing football instead of having to stay at home",

Answer (score 0):

E.g. minimal pairs:

- I would rather walk than run
- I walk instead of running
- I would rather eat apples than oranges
- I eat apples instead of oranges
- I would rather walk quickly than quietly
- I walk quickly instead of quietly

There really isn't much of a difference, except perhaps "would rather" implies preference whereas "instead of" implies substitution. But that might be nitpicking. And it doesn't seem to apply when using it to coordinate adverbs (last pair).

And no, your sentence is not correct if you substitute in "instead of", and it should be

> I'd rather **be playing** football instead of **staying** at home

But regardless, try to use "than" more as it is more suited in most contexts.

"rather than" vs "instead of" [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164010/when-to-use-rather-than-versus-instead-of)

Answer (score -2):

Your sentence is not correct. It should be:

*I'd rather play football instead of **staying** at home.*

Here is why:

In the following sentence the forms of the verbs "play" and "stay" are dictated by "I'd rather":

1. *I **would rather** **play** football than **stay** at home.*

In the following sentence the form of the verb "play" is dictated by "would rather" and the form of the verb "stay" is dictated by "instead of":

2. *I **would rather play** football **instead of staying** at home.*

However, as mentioned by @FumbleFingers, the above sentence sounds clunky due to a lack of parallelism. A more natural sentence would be:

3. *I **would rather be playing** football **instead of staying** at home.*

Out of the above three sentence, again as pointed out by @FumbleFingers, the first (**would rather**... **than**...) is the most natural.

Comment: I don't agree with your reasoning. The continuous/gerund in your final version looks clunky to my. At the very least, I'd expect the "parallelism" of *I would rather **be playing** football instead of staying at home*. But regardless of the verb form, ***than*** is far better than ***instead of*** in all such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I still think I got my reasoning right. The possible forms of "play" *are* dictated by "would rather" and the possible forms of "stay" *are* dictated by "instead of", aren't they? What you object to is the clunkiness of "I would rather play football instead of staying at home" due to a lack of parallelism, which I completely agree with. I had a nagging feeling that there was something not quite right with the sentence but couldn't exactly put my finder on it. I'm going to modify my answer to reflect this. Please do let me know what you think of the revised version.

Comment: Your answer is fine now.